# I encountered a numpy array error while writing a script for unconstrained gradient descent of a multi-variate function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to implement the following unconstrained gradient descent:
$x_{k+1}=x_{k}-\alpha_{k} \nabla f\left(x_{k}\right)$

The function that I'm trying to apply gradient descent on is the following:
$$
f\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)=x_{1}^{2}+2 \frac{1-\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} x_{1} x_{2}+x_{2}^{2}
$$

Below is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from itertools import product

plt.style.use('seaborn');
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 20;



def step_size(eps):
    
    return 1/2 * (3*eps+1)*(eps+1)/(eps+3)**2

def func(x,eps): #X refers to the configuration space
    
    return x[0]**2 + 2*(1-eps)/(1+eps) *x[0]*x[1] + x[1]**2

def grad_f(x,eps):
    
    grad1 = 2*x[0] + 2*(1-eps)/(1+eps) * x[1]
    grad2 = 2*(1-eps)/(1+eps) * x[0] + 2*x[1]
    
    grad_vec = np.vstack((grad1,grad2))
    
    
    return grad_vec

def descent(func,eps, grad_f, x0, step_size, tol=1e-5, max_iter=1000):
    # initialize x, f(x), and -f'(x)
    xk = x0
    fk = func(xk,eps)
    pk = -grad_f(xk,eps)
    # initialize number of steps, save x and f(x)
    num_iter = 0
    curve_x = [xk]
    curve_f= [fk]
    # take steps
    while abs(pk[0][0]) > tol and abs(pk[1][0])> tol and num_iter < max_iter:
        # calculate new x, f(x), and -f'(x)
        xk = xk + step_size(eps) * pk
        fk = func(xk,eps)
        pk = -grad_f(xk,eps)
        # increase number of steps by 1, save new x and f(x)
        num_iter += 1
        curve_x.append(xk)
        curve_f.append(fk)
    # print results
    if num_iter == max_iter:
        print('Gradient descent does not converge.')
    else:
        print('Solution found:\n  y = {:.4f}\n  x = {:.4f}'.format(fk, xk))
    
    return curve_x, curve_f

x0 = np.array([1,1])
eps = np.array([1, 0.1 , 0.01 , 0.001]);

x_trj = []
f = []

x_temp = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
x = np.array([x_temp,x_temp])
for i in eps:
    x,f = descent(func(x,i),i,grad_f(x,i),np.array([1,1]),step_size(i),tol=1e-5,max_iter=1000)
    x_trj.append(x)
    f.append(f)
```

I basically vectorized the equation such that [x1,x2] becomes xk. However, when I run the code the following error occurred, and I can't figure out what's wrong:

```
    x,f = descent(func(x,i),i,grad_f(x,i),x0=np.array([1,1]),step_size(i),tol=1e-5,max_iter=1000)
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument



 
    x,f = descent(func(x,i),i,grad_f(x,i),np.array([1,1]),step_size(i),tol=1e-5,max_iter=1000)


TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: `callable` is a general Python term for a function, something that is used with the `func()` syntax.  Something in that problem line is an array, rather than a function.  Did you even try to verify the nature of each term?  It may take more than a careful reading of your code.  You may have to test  the terms.

Comment: The first error points to this mx of arguments: `x0=np.array([1,1]),step_size(i),tol=1e-5`.  That's 2 keyword arguments with a a positional inbetween.

Comment: In `def descent(func,eps, grad_f,..., `func` is supposed to be a function, which is used  as `fk = func(xk,eps)`, etc.  But you provide its array outputs, `func(x,i)`,  Same for `grad_f`.  The error doesn't exactly point to this, but you may be showing an editing version of the error(s), not the full thing.